# Constraint on a character varying using numbers

Tags: sql, constraints

I've got this code (just an excerpt)...

```
CREATE TABLE "Degree"
(
  ippp_code character varying(5) CONSTRAINT four_or_five_chars_only CHECK (ippp_code >= 4 OR ippp_code <= 5) NOT NULL
)
```

What i'm try do is make the ippp_code a maximum of 5 characters or a mininum of 4 characters. So you can only enter 4 or 5 characters.

When I run the code I get an error message saying...

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying >= integer HINT: 
>   No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might
>   need to add explicit type casts.
>
> *** *Error* *****
>
> ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying >= integer SQL
>   state: 42883 Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument
>   type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

I wondering can I use the constraint I set using character varying? Also can I get a correction on the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE "Degree" 
( 
  ippp_code character varying(5) CONSTRAINT four_or_five_chars_only CHECK (length(ippp_code) >= 4 OR length(ippp_code) <= 5) NOT NULL 
)
```

You were trying to check that the value of ippp_code was between 4 and 5, not the length.

Comment: ERROR:  function len(character varying) does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

********** Error **********

ERROR: function len(character varying) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Also I just realised in my other code i've been checking that the value is between a certain number, instead of the length. Thanks for that.

So I need to use the len (or length) keyword to check the lenght of a character or integer?

Comment: Yes you need to use the correct keyword for whatever flavour of SQL you are using (For postgresql it's `length()`)

Comment: thanks again mate. So when you wrote len() you meant length()?

Comment: Yes it did not quite click that you were in a postgre environment. I've edited the answer to reflect.

Comment: how about if you want to set a length constraint on a integer type?

Comment: ucas_no integer CONSTRAINT ten_digits_only CHECK (length(ucas_no) >= 10 OR length(ucas_no) <= 10) NOT NULL

Comment: convert the integer type to a string.

Comment: Is this how to covert it?....ucas_no to_char(integer, string) CONSTRAINT ten_digits_only CHECK (length(ucas_no) >= 10 OR length(ucas_no) <= 10) NOT NULL

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9068/discussion-between-hkf-and-mr-teeth)

Comment: ok, check the message i left in chat. if you can fix that for me, i'll be greatful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE Degree
(
  ippp_code varchar2(5) not null, 
  CONSTRAINT four_or_five_chars_only 
  CHECK (length(ippp_code) between 4 and 5)
);
```

Comment: Thanks sql_mommy, your code works. Just need to take of the "2" in the "varchar2".

Comment: So I guess using the length keyword checks the length of the characters?

Comment: yes - exactly.  You didn't specify your database, so I just did it in mine, which is Oracle.  In SQLServer the datatype would be varchar, in Oracle it would be varchar2, and other DBs would have a different wording.  Similarly, the function for length is different in each database, too.

Comment: okay, thanks. I'm using PostgreSQL. While you're here do you mind if you can look at this question for me? http://bit.ly/GBsYPt